# Convert multiple files in one command

Tags: command-line, bash, convert

My folder looks like this:

```
➜  ls -l
total 437932
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wheel 16254039 Jun  1 20:45 DSC_0210.NEF
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wheel 83532064 Jun  1 21:16 DSC_0210.png
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wheel 16672363 Jun  1 20:45 DSC_0211.NEF
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wheel 16590658 Jun  1 20:46 DSC_0212.NEF
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wheel 17174603 Jun  1 20:46 DSC_0213.NEF
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wheel 17038931 Jun  1 20:47 DSC_0214.NEF
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wheel 17050255 Jun  1 20:48 DSC_0217.NEF
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wheel 17005150 Jun  1 20:48 DSC_0218.NEF
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wheel 17254947 Jun  1 20:49 DSC_0219.NEF
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wheel 16036682 Jun  1 20:49 DSC_0221.NEF
...
```

I can convert one NEF file at a time with:

```
convert DSC_0210.NEF DSC_0210.png
```

How can I convert all files with one command?

Answer (score 5):

From the directory where you have your files, you can do it with the following command:

```
for f in *.NEF; do convert "$f" "${f%.*}.png"; done
```

In the above command:

- We use a `for` loop (`for f in *.NEF; do ...; done`) that searches for all files ending in `.NEF` (`*.NEF`).
- For each found file (`f`) we use the `convert "$f" "${f%.*}.png"` command to convert the original file (`"$f"`) to `.png` by removing the extension of the original file (`${f%.*}`) and appending the `.png` extension (`"${f%.*}.png"`).